# django admin populate fields in inlined models

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

i am working on a website for a private school, in witch i have to calculate for each month a total price based on list of chosen services.

i am using 3 models

```
class Eleve(models.Model):
    ...

class Tarif(models.Model):

    eleve = models.OneToOneField(Eleve, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assurance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default="1000")
    frais = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default="750")
    transport = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default="350")
    garde = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default="250")
    ...

class Facture(models.Model):
    month_choices = (
        ('9', 'Septembre'),
        ('10', 'Octobre'),
        ...
    )
    eleve = models.ForeignKey(Eleve, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=month_choices)
    frais = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    transport = models.BooleanField()
    garde = models.BooleanField()
    total = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    avance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
```

Eleve == Student

in admin.py, the models Tarif and Facture are display as TabularInline like so:

```
class TarifInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tarif
    formset = RequiredInlineFormSet
    can_delete = False

class FactureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Facture
```

what i need is when i check transport or/and garde, the total field should be filled with the sum of current_eleve.tarif.transport and cuurent_eleve.tarif.garde

the field total must be stored in database for some cases..

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To do it on the server side, you will probably want to use `pre_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals) or override the `save` methods of your models.

To do it in the backend web interface, you could use some JS snippet (django.contrib.admin comes with [batteries included](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/)). But, never trust the data that comes from a client, and always calculate the important values on the server side.

Comment: i want do it client side.. could you wright some code for example please

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not comfortable enough with javascript to give examples in it :(